# How to make the "Don't save" or "delete" options the default?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I often start up an app to do something quickly, e.g. quicktime, record some audio, check it out, then I'll <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> out of it.

I don't know about other people but generally for me <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> means "be gone as fast as possible"

I always get prompted with these though:

[image]
[image]

Can I make the "Delete" or "Don't save"-type options the default?

So I can just hit enter when the dialogue appears and quit the app without saving any changes to that document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Command Backspace (⌘⌫)

This works in all the apps I've tried (Preview, QuickTime, ScriptEditor):

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to ask to quit, then
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> to quit without saving.

It seems <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> selects the *Don't Save* equivalent in all these dialogues.

Answer (score 0):

The options you want to make the default, are the options that are the most likely to cause data loss, and so they are not the default for a reason. However, you mentioned quitting using the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> key, so you’re not afraid to use keyboard shortcuts.

I mention this because the Mac OS usually allows you to select a button in a dialog by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> and the first letter of the button’s text. In the ‘Delete’ or ‘Don’t save’ case, this would mean you can dismiss the dialog and not save by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. For ‘Revert’, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

It’s not as convenient as <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it’s still two keystrokes. And without opening you up to potential data loss by default.

Comment: This didn't work for me in either of my examples (Preview nor QuickTime)

Comment: I am surprised - it works in the default File dialog boxes. I’ve been using these shortcuts for years

Comment: DIdn't work in script editor either

Comment: This doesn't work. In Preview, at least, where I tried it.

Comment: The default these days is Cmd/Backspace, though some apps still hang onto the old Cmd/D.